# PHP PDO Form is not inserting/updating into the database

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have two problems. I have one form that isn't inserting data into the database and I have an update query that isn't updating. The updating query doesn't go with the form. Its supposed to automatically update when you go to the page. My guess is they both have the same problem. I have included my config in both. Every things accounted for. I have already tried bindValue. Please, if you need any more info just comment below and ask. I don't usually like posting on here because some of you guys can be a little harsh for just not including information or something. I will kindly cooperate with any of you. Thank you for the help in advance!

PHP for Form:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {  
    $touser = $_POST['ToUser'];
    $subject = $_POST['Subject'];
    $message = $_POST['Message'];
    $from = $usersession;
    $timestamp = date("Y/m/d H:i:s");
    $read = 0;
    $trash = 0;
    if (empty($touser) || empty($subject) || empty($message)) {
        echo "<b>Please fill out all fields</b>";
    } else {
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO Messaging (ToUser,Subject,Message,FromUser,Timestamp,Read,Trash) VALUES (:ToUser,:Subject,:Message,:FromUser,:Timestamp,:Read,:Trash)");
        $query->bindParam(':ToUser', $touser);
        $query->bindParam(':Subject', $subject);
        $query->bindParam(':Message', $message);
        $query->bindParam(':FromUser', $from);
        $query->bindParam(':Timestamp', $timestamp);
        $query->bindParam(':Read', $read);
        $query->bindParam(':Trash', $trash);
        $query->execute();
        echo "<b>Message Sent</b>";
    }
}
?>
```

Heres the HTML form to that:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label" for="compose-to">To</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" id="compose-to" name="ToUser" class="form-control form-control-borderless" placeholder="Enter a Username">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="cc-input" class="form-group display-none">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label" for="compose-to-cc">Cc</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10">
            <input type="email" id="compose-to-cc" name="compose-to-cc" class="form-control form-control-borderless" placeholder="Enter Cc emails..">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="bcc-input" class="form-group display-none">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label" for="compose-to-bcc">Bcc</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10">
            <input type="email" id="compose-to-bcc" name="compose-to-bcc" class="form-control form-control-borderless" placeholder="Enter Bcc emails..">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label" for="compose-subject">Subject</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10">
            <input type="text" id="compose-subject" name="Subject" class="form-control form-control-borderless" placeholder="Your subject..">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 control-label" for="compose-message">Message</label>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10">
            <textarea id="compose-message" name="Message" rows="20" class="form-control textarea-editor" placeholder="Your message.."></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group form-actions">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Send</button>
            <!-- Uncomment for draft button
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Save Draft</button>
            -->
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Heres the update part:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id']; 
$read = 1;
$query = $db->prepare('UPDATE Messaging SET Read = :read WHERE Id = :id');
$query->bindParam(':id', $id); 
$query->bindParam(':read', $read);
$query->execute();
?>
```

I FIGURED IT OUT. I added `` to all the fields and it worked. Thanks anyway for the help!

Comment: **`$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`**  If you aren't checking the return from the `prepare` and `execute` functions, you can set an attribute on the connection so that PDO will raise an exception if an error occurs. (Not always the most appropriate solution, but it's better than ignoring errors.)

Comment: `Read` is a reserved word use back ticks http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html